# gRPC Service Type

Tags: service, types, streaming, grpc

Do I need a streaming RPC if the server needs to send back more than 1 object to the client with each call? In particular, the client will call the server with an ID and the server will respond with a list of objects matching that ID and dump that list to a file. Is streaming required for this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the objects are available at the same time, or if you are ok to hold the response until they are all available, you can just respond a protobuf message that aggregates all the objects you want to respond. Otherwise, you need (server) streaming.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Muxi, a related question for you. How can I call a gRPC client stub from an external Django application? Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with that unfortunately. I suggest you consult that on the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grpc-io)